# Python 3 MQTT client storing received payload in Sqlite - Open DB once, store many times, finally close db?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, mqtt, paho

I have a Python 3.6 code that connects to MQTT and subscribes to a topic. Every time that the callback function "on_message" gets triggered, it instantiates a class that has a single method that does the following:   Opens the db file, save the received data, closes the db file.

The Python script described above works almost fine.  It receives about 7 MQTT messages per second, so for each message it needs to `[Open_DB - Save_Data - Close_DB]`.  There are some messages getting PUBACK but not saved, perhaps due to some many unnecesary operations, so I want to improve:

I spent a lot of time (not an expert) trying to create a class that would open the db once, write many thousands of times to the db, and only when done, close the db file. to create a class that would have three methods:

```
1. MyDbClass.open_db_file()
2. MyDbClass.save_data()
3. MyDbClass.close_db_file()
```

The problem as you may guess is that it is not possible to call  `MyDbClass.save_data()` from within the "on_message" callback, even when the object has been placed on a global variable.   Here is the non-working code with the proposed idea, that I cleaned up for easier reading:

```
# -----------------------------
```

## This code has been cleaned-up for faster reading

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import json
import sqlite3
```

## Global Variables

```
db_object = ""

class MyDbClass():


def __init__(self):
    pass

def open_db_file(self, dbfile):
   self.db_conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
   return self.db_conn

def save_data(self, json_data):
    self.time_stamp = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    self.data = json.loads(json_data)
    self.sql = '''INSERT INTO trans_reqs (received, field_a, field_b, field_c) \
                  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'''
    self.fields_values = ( self.time_stamp, self.data['one'], self.data['two'], self.data['three']] )
    self.cur = self.db_conn.cursor()
    self.cur.execute(self.sql, self.fields_values)
    self.db_conn.commit()            

def close_db_file(self):    
    self.cur.close()
    self.db_conn.close()


def on_mqtt_message(client, userdata, msg):

global db_object

m_decode = msg.payload.decode("utf-8","ignore")

db_object.save_data(m_decode)



def main():  



global db_object
```

## Database to use - Trying to create an object to manage DB tasks (from MyDbClass)

```
db_file =  "my_filename.sqlite"
db_object = MyDbClass.open_db_file(db_file)

# MQTT -- Set varibles
broker_address= "..."
port = 1883
client_id = "..."
sub_topic = "..."
sub_qos = 1
# MQTT -- Instanciate the MQTT Client class and set callbacks
client = mqtt.Client(client_id)
client.on_connect = on_mqtt_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_mqtt_disconnect
client.on_message = on_mqtt_message
client.on_log = on_mqtt_log
client.clean_session = True
#client.username_pw_set(usr, password=pwd)          #set username and password

print('Will connect to broker ', broker_address)
client.connect(broker_address, port=port, keepalive=45 )
client.loop_start()
client.subscribe(sub_topic, sub_qos)
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Disconnects MQTT
    client.disconnect()
    client.loop_stop()
    print("....................................")
    print("........ User Interrupted ..........")
    print("....................................")

db_object.close_db_file()

client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help on how to do this will be greatly appreciated!